# Laravel Assigning Middleware within Controller’s constructor, should the constructor include parent::__construct()?

Tags: laravel, constructor

Here is example for

Laravel: Assigning Middleware within Controller’s constructor

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/laravel/laravel_controllers.htm

```
class UserController extends Controller {
   public function __construct(){
   $this->middleware('auth');
   }
}
```

My question is should it be

```
class UserController extends Controller {
   public function __construct(){
      $this->middleware('auth');
      parent::__onstruct();
  }
}
```

Due to the UserConstroller override the __construct. If it does not include parent::__construct(), the parent constructor will not be called. That could be a problem, correct?